# WiFI does not work on Windows 10 BootCamp - Drops in and out

Tags: wifi, bootcamp, windows

**Update: There was a new driver released on 4/20/2018 for Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter, version 7.35.118.83, but the Apple update is only now pushing it (7/9/2018).  Just installed it. Let's see how it goes.**

WiFi is consistently dropping at random times regardless of network.

Question : how do I fix it so I have a reliable consistent wifi connection when I use Windows 10?

I have a MacBook Pro, purchased late 2017.

WiFi will randomly disconnect when I run Windows 10.  It works better on certain networks than others but it's always intermittent. Even on very robust networks it will eventually begin to drop. Once it drops it sometimes will simply not reconnect. Other times the drivers will randomly be disabled, not sure if this has to do with windows updates.

I tried manually installing and uninstalling drivers, rolling back drivers, installing and reinstalling the windows support software, and even using third party driver support software. Wifi connection still drops randomly with no perceivable pattern.

I went to the apple store and I was simply told that this is a windows issue.  I had windows running on a MacBook air (2010) and never experienced these issues.  It also seems they haven't come up with an update for the driver in almost two years. I ran out of ideas, any pointers on how to fix the wifi connection problem is appreciated.

Hardware info -

Manufacturer:   Broadcom

Description:    Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter

Driver version: 7.35.118.68

Comment: Can I have more information on what needs clarification? Wifi does not work on my MacBook pro (2017) when I'm running Windows 10 using the boot camp installation. It will randomly disconnect.  How do I fix it so that I have consistent reliable wifi connection

Comment: Does the Mac side experience any wifi issues such as drops?

Comment: No, when I'm running the Mac OS it's flawless.  I'm thinking it may have to do with activating windows.  I'll give that a shot and see if it changes anything. Call me crazy, but I noticed that windows will prevent certain things from working specially if it's asking to update. Now it has an impossible to remove virus. So the WiFi thing may be a subtle way to push a user to activate windows.

Comment: Activated Windows, problem still persists. Wifi randomly disconected for a good minute. This is unbelievable...

Comment: You may need to backup your Windows files and then delete/reset up BootCamp.

Comment: Yes, I've just been avoiding it because I would have to re-sync my dropbox and outlook which is nearly 100gb.  I would have to look up how to back up those file with out having to resync.

Comment: If they are saved on their server then they will come back on.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1214251/windows-10-wi-fi-too-slow-on-bootcamp-after-update Solved. This seems a problem of power management.

Comment: I have the same problem!!!
MacBook Pro 15" late 2017 i7 2.9

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**: Set the Power Output of the Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter to 25%

[image: Device Manager Properties Dialog]

The solution was found with a Google search for "macbook pro wireless disconnects randomly bootcamp windows 10" which returned the following video as result 2 [Fix APPLE bootcamp wifi drop out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zLgEIX5wn4)

My System:

- Macbook Pro 10,1 (Early 2013)
- Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
- Driver Version: 7.35.118.73

I have been suffering with slowly degrading WiFi connection over the last couple of months (approximately).  Recently, it has got the the point where the connection will drop out and reconnect 2 or 3 times per minute.  That was really only noticeable when using a VPN connection over Cisco AnyConnect - otherwise browsing just appeared to be very slow at times.  I found that disabling the WiFi and re-enabling it would provide relief for a few minutes.

Things I tried that did not work:

- Installing later drivers (not signed by Microsoft) Broadcom_BCM43xx_7.35.317.3-Win10 accessed from [Search for Broadcom 43XX drivers - result 1](http://www.driver-wireless.com/broadcom-bcm43xx-driver-win7810.html)
- Unchecking the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" option on the Power Management tab of the Device Properties Dialog.

I hope this works as well for others as it has for me...

Comment: This helped me on MBP mid 2017, had constant disconnects for both 2.4 and 5ghz networks on Airport Extreme

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  No, this solution does not work on my Macbook. I Tried this, and many other settings all yielding close to no results. Apple just recently released a new driver for WiFi. Hopefully it will work better than what was available before.

Answer (score 1):

The bootcamp tools installation did not help.
I uninstalled the driver and restarted the mac. Then everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have similar Wifi problem with MacbookPro 2017. The Wifi always drop and fail to reconnect to a certain network. I found the root caused is due to the Mobile Hotspot function in Windows 10 and my Wifi problem is gone after I disable the "Microsoft Direct Virtual Adapter #2" in Device Manager. Hope this helps!

[image: Network Adapter]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on macOS Catalina (Macbook pro 2015). WiFi was consistently dropping at random times regardless of network when working on Windows Bootcamp.
After running update

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Apple Software Update\SoftwareUpdate.exe

It seems have fixed the problem with 2.4 GHz wifi.

[image]